# how to return length of a list from a class in python

Tags: python

So I get this error when I try to get the len() of my list from my class:
TypeError: object of type 'Stuff' has no len()
when I try:

```
>>> s = Stuff()
>>> len(s)
error instead of showing 0 like:
>>> l = []
>>> len(l)
0
```

Code:

```
class Stuff():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []
```

Comment: Why would your class `Stuff` have a length?  If you are implementing a new variety of sequence, you should consider inheriting from one of the base classes designed for that purpose, which will supply an implementation of `__len__` for you.

Comment: I think what you should do is: len(s.lst)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the [`__len__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) special method like so:

```
class Stuff():
    def __init__(self):
         self.lst = []
    def __len__(self):
         return len(self.lst)
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
>>> s = Stuff()
>>> len(s)
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `__len__` special method

```
class Stuff(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bits = []
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.bits)
```

I highly recommend reading through the docs page on special methods.
http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

There are a fair number of neat things you can do, such as defining how methods such as

`Stuff() += 3` or `Stuff()[4]` behaves.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `len` can be "a sequence (string, tuple or list) or a mapping (dictionary)": http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len

It **cannot** simply be an object, **unless** that object explicitly defines a `__len__` method. This is the method that implicitly gets called by the `len` function.